# SyntaxError in any() test

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, any, or-operator

I am pretty new to python syntax ... how do I use the `or` operator in this scenario?

To check if files end with either '.txt' or '.sm3dump', I tried to use `any()`, but I got a SyntaxError:

```
if any(filename.endswith('.txt'), filename.endswith('.sm3dump'))
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: For or operator simply type `or`. And put a `:` at the end of your `if`.
`if filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.sm3dump'):` you can find this quickly using google though...

Answer (score 4):

You've called [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with two arguments:

```
any(filename.endswith('.txt'), filename.endswith('.sm3dump'))
#   <----- argument #1 ----->  <------- argument #2 ------->
```

... but it only takes one, which must be an iterable (a list, tuple, etc.):

```
any([filename.endswith('.txt'), filename.endswith('.sm3dump')])
#   <-------------- one list with two elements -------------->
```

If you wanted to use `or` instead, it's straightforward:

```
filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.sm3dump')
```

A common idiom when using `any()` to perform multiple similar tests is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression):

```
any([filename.endswith(ext) for ext in ('.txt', '.sm3dump')])
#   <----------------- list comprehension ----------------->
```

```
any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in ('.txt', '.sm3dump'))
#   <-------- generator expression (no brackets) -------->
```

Although in this case, you can actually supply a tuple of strings to [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith), and it'll check them all:

```
filename.endswith(('.txt', '.sm3dump'))
```

Whichever test you use, you need to remember to end your `if` statement with a colon:

```
if filename.endswith(('.txt', '.sm3dump')):
    # do something ...
```

Comment: Eric: To discover things like the last part of Zero's answer, use `help` at an interactive prompt to quickly check the signature and use of functions and classes.  In particular, `>>> help(str.endswith)` ends with " suffix can also be a tuple of strings to try".